# Cordova plugin string translation

Tags: ios, angular, cordova, permissions

I have my angular project and use Cordova to make the apk.
My app was refused on submit on the App Store, because I don't give the translation, when I request permission to access camera, location and other permissions.

My app have three language support (English, Spanish and Portuguese)

Here are the plugins with the default string message.

```
<edit-config file="*-Info.plist" mode="merge" target="NSCameraUsageDescription">
   <string>need camera access to take pictures</string>
</edit-config>
<edit-config file="*-Info.plist" mode="merge" target="NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription">
   <string>need location access to find somethings nearby (address, devices, installers)</string>
</edit-config>
<edit-config file="*-Info.plist" mode="merge" target="NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription">
   <string>need photo library access to get pictures from there</string>
</edit-config>
<edit-config file="*-Info.plist" mode="merge" target="NSPhotoLibraryAddUsageDescription">
    <string>need photo library access to save pictures there</string>
</edit-config>
```

How can I translate the permission string message?

Comment: You can try this plugin: https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-localization-strings

Comment: do you have some examples using this plugin? I don't have undestand how should I leave the configuration in the config.xml file

Comment: Did you find any solution for this?